# (variable name) is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Table

Tags: asp.net, sql

This is my code for taking data from the database (i use dataset) :

```
public DataSet getJobVacancy(GetJobVacancyData data)
{
    try
    {
        string _SPName  = "dbo.SearchJob";
        SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[3];
        sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@Keyword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);

        if(data.Keyword == null || data.Keyword == "")
            sqlParam[0].Value = DBNull.Value;
        else
            sqlParam[0].Value = data.Keyword;

        sqlParam[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        sqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@LocationID", SqlDbType.SmallInt);

        if(data.LocationID == null)
            sqlParam[1].Value = DBNull.Value;
        else
            sqlParam[1].Value = data.LocationID;

        sqlParam[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        sqlParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@ExperienceYears", SqlDbType.TinyInt);

        if(data.ExperienceYears == null)
            sqlParam[2].Value = DBNull.Value;
        else
            sqlParam[2].Value = data.ExperienceYears;

        sqlParam[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SystemConfiguration.AMDP2_ConnectionString,
                                        CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                                       _SPName,
                                       sqlParam);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

And this is my setter-getter :

```
public string JobVacancyID { get; set; }
public string PostingDate { get; set; }
public string ClosingDate { get; set; }
public string Position { get; set; }
public string Location { get; set; }
public string Keyword { get; set; }
public string LocationID { get; set; }
public string ExperienceYears { get; set; }
```

This one is my Repeater's data bound :

```
protected void rptJob_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView data = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

        Literal ltrDatePosted = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrDatePosted");
        Literal ltrClosingDate = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrClosingDate");
        LinkButton lbtnPosition = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbtnPosition");
        Literal ltrLocation = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrLocation");
        Literal ltrExpYears = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrExpYears");
        Literal ltrJobVacancyID = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrJobVacancyID");

        ltrDatePosted.Text = data["PostingDate"].ToString();
        ltrClosingDate.Text = data["ClosingDate"].ToString();
        lbtnPosition.Text = data["Position"].ToString();
        ltrLocation.Text = data["LocationName"].ToString();
        ltrExpYears.Text = data["ExperienceYears"].ToString();
        ltrJobVacancyID.Text = data["JobVacancyID"].ToString(); //this is where the error occured
    }
}
```

This is my sql query/stored procedure (i have run this query and the JobVacancyID column is in the result) :

```
BEGIN
SELECT JobVacancyID, PostingDate, ClosingDate, Position, b.LocationName, ExperienceYears FROM TRJobVacancy a
JOIN LTLocation b on a.LocationID = b.LocationID    
WHERE Position LIKE '%'+ COALESCE(@Keyword,Position) + '%' AND COALESCE(@LocationID, a.LocationID) = a.LocationID AND COALESCE(@ExperienceYears,ExperienceYears)  = ExperienceYears
```

The error that i got is : "**JobVacancyID is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Table**"

And the confusing fact's are :
1. It's only give an error at data["JobVacancyID"], the others is smooth.
2. I think i don't have a table named Table(the error said this)
Thanks :D

Comment: **Never** write `throw ex;`.  Get rid of that `catch` block.

Comment: Agreed. If you're just going to throw the exception, then the try/catch is unnecessary. Also, before you set `ltrJobVacancyID.Text`, check to make sure that the column exists by doing `data.Table.Columns.Contains("JobVacancyID")`. I'm wondering if maybe there's a typo somewhere. What's the `[variable name]` actually say in the error?

Comment: Done,but the error is still there...
Thanks :D

Comment: @SPFFiredrake the variable name is JobVacancyID :D
And when i tried to use data.Table.Columns.Contains("JobVacancyID") it's said "'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a definition for 'Table' and no extension method 'Table' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
And please note that i use a DataView :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SORRY ALL.....i just miss type the variable..it tooks around 3hours to realize it @_@

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but as well as setting the type, I had missed a couple of datafield values too.  mainly on GridTemplateColumn columns.